# How do I add a bullet to a textbox? (I tried and it says shapes have to paragraph attribute?

Tags: python, python-pptx

square = shape.add_textbox(Inches(3), Inches(3), Inches(1), Inches(1))
I want this textbox to have bullets. I tried adding a textframe instead, but the size of the texframe cannot be adjusted and I want multiple boxes with bullets.

I tried adding a textframe instead, but the size of the texframe cannot be adjusted and I want multiple boxes with bullets.

Comment: Have you seen this similar question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384134/add-bullet-list-using-python-pptx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this to add bullet points...

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement

presentation = Presentation("no bullets.pptx")
for slide in presentation.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        txt = shape._sp
        rId = txt.xpath('./p:txBody')[0]
        for jh in rId:
            rId2 = jh

            ii = OxmlElement("a:pPr")
            ii.set("indent","-285750")
            ii.set("marL","285750")
            rId2.insert(0,ii)

            jj = OxmlElement("a:buFont")
            jj.set("charset","0")
            jj.set("pitchFamily","34")
            jj.set("panose","020B0604020202020204")
            jj.set("typeface","Arial")
            ii.insert(0,jj)

            kk = OxmlElement("a:buChar")
            kk.set("char","•")
            ii.insert(1,kk)

presentation.save("bullets.pptx")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the textframe resizing question, you set the size of the shape. Not the textframe that is part of it.